# Is there an intrinsic physical meaning for characteristic curves of a PDE?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-equations

For partial differential equations (such as those that govern many physical phenomena), there exist characteristic curves, along which the equations can be reduced to total derivatives and solved. The number and type of characteristic curves seems to depend on the nature of the PDE in question - whether it is elliptic, parabolic or hyperbolic.

For example, in the case of the Navier-Stokes Equations for fluid flow, in the subsonic region, the PDE system is elliptic, in which case the characteristic curves are complex (not real). However, in the supersonic flow regime, the PDE system becomes hyperbolic and the characteristics become real - they physically correspond to the 'mach cone' that defines the region of a flow that can be influenced by a disturbance at a given point.

So, my question is, in *general*, do characteristic curves of a system of PDEs have an intrinsic physical meaning? In the supersonic flow case, real characteristics seem to define a region of the flow within which information can travel. Is that also true for other systems of PDEs found in Physics in general, if we look beyond just the fluid dynamics case?

If it is true, then what is the theoretical basis for the physical meaning? I.e. why should curves along which the equations can be expressed as total derivatives define a sub-region that limits the travel of information?

Comment: Would be nice to know the reason for the downvote ...

Comment: Of course there is an intrinsic physical interpretation. It's going to depend on the equation to explain which one it is, but the characteristics are fundamental to the behavior of the system always.

Comment: @tpg2114 so, it's not possible to say anything in general about the physical meaning of characteristic curves, without looking at specific PDEs?

Comment: Nothing more than you've already said really -- they are the direction along which "information" "travels." What "information" means and "travels" means will depend on your physical system. They are also the direction along which PDE's become ODE's, which again the meaning will depend on the system. And so it's not a very well researched original question and it's quite broad.

Comment: @tpg2114  Perhaps I could have phrased the question better. I guess what I am getting at is: what does directions in which a PDE reduces to an ODE have to do with 'information travel'? What is the link there?

Comment: The question is phrased just fine. Some people here downvote when they fail to understand the question or don't know the answer.

Comment: Related question: [Why are certain PDE called "elliptic", "hyperbolic", or "parabolic"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3650360/64206) And [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3651725/64206) there.